# Swiftmailer and smtp gmail in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

I tried to configure swiftmailer in yii2 advanced. I read the tutorial and I use the code in here, but I'm still got an error.

In my case, guest must submit his name and his email before download Ebook. And then, they will get an email from my office which contains an ebook download link.

My configuration in `common/config/main-local.php`

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [ 
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',

        ],     
    ],
],
```

In my `controller/GuestController.php`

```
public function actionCreate()
{       
    $model = new guest();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('myaccount@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($model->email)
        ->setSubject('halo')
        ->setTextBody('body')
        ->send();
        $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['buku/index']);
    }
    else{
        return $this->renderAjax('create',[
                'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form Guest

```
<div class="guest-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nama')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?php
    echo Alert::widget([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'alert-warning',
    ],
    'body' => '[Alert] Check your email for Download',
    ]);
?> 
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And my error,

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

How can I fix this? Thank you, **It's Solved**

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the settings with `encryption` as `tls` and port `587` and you dont need to set the `'useFileTransport' => false,` as now it defaults to false see [**`here`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-basemailer#$useFileTransport-detail)

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer' ,
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport' ,
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com' ,
                'username' => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587' ,
                'encryption' => 'tls' ,
            ] ,
        ] ,
```

Comment: I use your code, but I get error, stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: The operation completed successfully :(

Comment: are you using the current code on localhost @Ayunda can you show full trace for the exception, what `code` does it say

Comment: and in my code i specified the `tls` encrytion did you do so ?

Comment: yes, I use port `587` `tls` and I not set `'useFileTransport' => false`. but I get an error  `stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: The operation completed successfully`